# Что такое *this?

Tags: c++

```
Vector3 operator = (const Vector3 &v1)
{

    if (&v1 == this)
        return *this;
    return Vector3(this->x = v1.x, this->y = v1.y, this->z = v1.z);
}
```

Возвращаю `*this`. А что такое `*this`. Что в нем хранится? В данном случае в нем хранятся элементы `x, y, z` или что? Можно пожалуйста какое нибудь объяснение на пальцах.

Comment: Если один из ответов решил вашу проблему, пометьте соответствующий ответ как верный, для этого нажмите галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 4):

`this` - указатель на объект, в данном случае на объект типа `Vector3`.

`*this` - объект.

```
    class Vector3
    {};
    ...
    Vector3 vector3;
    //this - указатель на vector3 в пределах объекта vector3
// для каждого объекта будет this
```

P.S нужно возвращать ссылку на `Vector3`:

```
Vector3 &operator = (const Vector3 &v1)
```

[operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

[‘this’ pointer in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/)

Comment: Для того чтобы ускорить метод?

Comment: Нет, тут дело не в ускорении, а в возвожности присваивания типа `(a = b) = c`, а если бы вы вернули не ссылку, то вышеприведённая конструкция не скомпилируется, скомпилируется только `a = (b = c)`. Поэтому рекомендуют возвращать ссылку (но это не обязательно, просто рекомендация).

Comment: А если бы я вернул сам обьект например return Vector3(this->x = v1.x, this->y = v1.y, this->z=v1.z) В плане почему не скомпилируется

Comment: В этом случае вы сначала присвоили в текущий объект новые значения, а затем зачем-то создали копию себя и вернули эту копию. Это синтаксически корректно, но довольно бессмысленно. Так делать не рекомендуется.

Comment: @Kaznachei , при `A operator =` будет вызван конструктор копирования

Comment: Вот, а можно,пожалуйста, обьяснитЬ причину бессмысленности. Я как бы понимаю, что я возвращаю копию самого себя, когда можно вернутЬ себя. И возвращать ссылку, а не создаватЬ копию, это для некоего ускорения ? Создание копии все равно же занимает какое то место в памяти (но, насколЬко я понимаю, потом удалится)

Comment: @bobtorus , про конструктор копирования поподробнее, пожалуйста. Оператор присваивания и конструктор копирования это разные вещи, и они вообще говоря не перенаправляются друг на друга...

Comment: Кстати, минусовал я, потому что  незнающие люди могут не понять правильно из за плохого обьяснения

Comment: @Kaznachei, а кто сказал, что нужно копию возвращать?

Comment: @Kaznachei , бессмысленность в том, что вы делаете лишнюю копию, вот смотрите, например вы создали объект: `int x;` , затем делаете его копию: `int y; y = x;`, и возвращаете: `return y;` , не лучше ли сразу сделать `return x;` ? Сэкономили лишнее присваивание.

Comment: @zcorvid,  http://tpcg.io/R1y79L

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, справедливо

Comment: @bobtorus , если бы вы добавили вывод и в операторе присваивания, вы бы увидели, что вызвался именно он, а не конктруктор копирования, а тот вызов конструктора копирования, который вы увидели, это копирование из-за того, что вы возвращаете `A` по значению, а не по ссылке, сделайте тип возврата `A&`, и вызова конструктора копирования больше не будет: [ссылка](http://cpp.sh/8vmwf)

Comment: @zcorvid, я и говорил, что operator= может вызвать конструктор копирования. Почему я и написал возвращать по ссылке в ответе

Comment: @bobtorus , я понял, в первый раз вы не очень чётко сформулировали свою мысль, и было непонятно, что именно вы имели ввиду. Но тут можно и дальше начать спорить, ведь есть RVO :) Однако это не отменяет тот факт, что возвращать по ссылке правильнее...

Comment: @zcorvid, [RVO and operator=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250043/why-doesnt-rvo-happen-for-assignment-operator-c) =)

Comment: @bobtorus , спасибо, не знал. Тогда тем более, даже спорить не о чём :)

Answer (score 3):

### В `*this` находится ссылка на текущий экземпляр класса.

В вашем случае `*this` имеет тип `Vector3&` , если косвенно судить по приведённому коду, то скорее всего в нём содержатся переменные `x, y, z`, как вы и написали.

PS. У вас не совсем корректная реализация оператора присваивания, корректнее будет так:

```
Vector3& operator = (const Vector3 &v1)
{
    if (&v1 != this)
    {
        x = v1.x;
        y = v1.y;
        z = v1.z;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: в *this   находится ссылка, или это и есть ссылька?

Comment: *this указатель на сыллку? Ссылку моей переменной

Comment: Не понимаю, то как этот метод работает. У меня есть Vector3 myvector = anotherVector. Я перегрузил оператор присваивания. Отправляю в метод ссылку на anotherVector и работаю с ней и моим вектором.  И в строчке return *this я же возвращаю сам указатель на myvector. Так?

Comment: @Kaznachei, *- разыменование указателя

Comment: @Kaznachei , верно, вы сначала в `myvector` заносите новые значения (делаете присваивание), а затем возвращаете ссылку на себя же (то есть ссылку на `myvector`), что необходимо для многоступенчатых присваиваний типа `a = b = c`.

Comment: Да, каждый обьект содержит неявный указатель this на самого себя.  Этот указатель доступен только членам класса. Его разыменование, как и сдругими указательями  есть ссылька на обьект(вы возвращаете этот же обьект)

Comment: Не оченЬ понял что это значит разыменование указателя

Comment: @Kaznachei , про разыменования указателя лучше почитать отдельно, на Википедии в разделе "Указатель (тип данных)" неплохо это описано.

Comment: это значит получение обьекта, чей адрес содержит указатель (*this, *pointer есть разыменование, т.е.  это  еще одно имя обьекта)

Comment: @zcorvid *"В вашем случае `*this` имеет тип `Vector3&`"* Нет, *выражения* никогда не имеют ссылочные типы. `*this` - это lvalue типа `Vector3`. Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48388647/2752075